# Were Priestly and Davey wrong about about "Order: A Theory with A View" being written by Ivan Rival?

Tags: mathematics

The textbook [Introduction to Lattices and Order](https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Lattices-Order-B-Davey/dp/0521784514) by Priestly and Davey mentions in its first edition preface:

> In a proselytizing article, Order: a. theory with a. view [in Kla.ssifikation und Ord:nung, INDEKS, Frankfurt, 1989], Ivan Rival discusses tbe modern role of order.

I don't see this article

- on his [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Rival)
- on his [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=-WDlg78AAAAJ&hl=en)
- on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22Order%3A+A+Theory+with+a+View%22)
- or on [this page](https://ivanrival.com/math_publications.html) dedicated to his article.

Did this article exist but never make it into a modern repository? Or is it misnamed in this reference, going by a different name among Rival's articles?

Comment: Maybe its in this book: https://books.google.com/books/about/Klassifikation_und_Ordnung.html?id=q9DgAAAAMAAJ

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingetraut_Dahlberg for info about the founder of the INDEKS publishing house .  Check out https://www.worldcat.org/title/607899935 for possible locations of copies.